# How to automatically connect the Eclipse debugger when the android app is restarted on the device?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse. I have a breakpoint on onCreate that I want to catch in debug mode when my application is restarted by android because of multitasking. I can connect the Eclipse debugger to my restarted app on the DDMS perspective, but I am never fast enough to catch the breakpoint in onCreate. How to automatically connect the Eclipse debugger when the android app is restarted on the device?

Comment: `I am never fast enough to catch the breakpoint` - What do you mean? The debugger stops on breakpoint automatically. Are you sure you are in debug mode?

Comment: @code monkey: When I multitask, the debugger is disconnected, it does no appear anymore on the DDMS perspective. If I switch back to the app on the device then the app reappears on the DDMS persepctive, but the debugger is not connected to it. I have to manually connect. But I am not fast enough with the manual connect to catch the breakpoint in onCreate()

Comment: I never needed to chase breakpoints, but see my answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

Run the app in debug mode. Right click on project there will a option **Debug as** below Run as.

Run the app in debug mode. But don't forget to add break point first before running app in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

> is restarted by android because of multitasking

Not sure what you really mean by this, but if this imprecise description refers to asynchronous operations (i.e. using `AsyncTask`) then you may want to add this line before your breakpoint set in code that is run on other than main task:

```
Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Please note that to make it work you need to launch your app in debugging mode (<kbd>F11</kbd>)

Comment: Is there a similar method in plain JDK? i.e. non-Android.